# Effect of polarizer on light's intensity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, visible-light, polarization

If you take unpolarized light and pass it through a polarizer, it's intensity will be half of what it was (ideally). Following Malus' Law I'd issume that if I pass this now polarized light through another polarizer that is parallel, the intensity should stay the same (half of the original). However, the reading I was given suggests that the final result would be the multiplication of the two (a quarter). Is this just a confusing thing or am I wrong?

Comment: Unless you spent a lot of money on the polarizers, they likely have significant losses. The usual plastic polarizers in physics labs are pretty lousy...

Comment: Yes, that why I said ideally. But loss or no loss, what I'm trying to get at is whether the transmitance of the two should be (close to) that of the first polarizer it pases through, orthe product of both transmitances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malus's Law ($I_\mathrm{out}=I_\mathrm{in}\cos^2(\theta)$) applies to the second ideal polarizer.  If it's parallel to the first, $\theta=0$ and 100% of the light that hits it will get through.  Since this is half of the original unpolarized light, half of the original light will get through the set (but it will be completely polarized now).

Realistic polarizers aren't nearly this good.